# Source for Names to use in web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

Can anyone suggest a good source of names that I can use to help analyze some tables on web pages.

The first column of the tables I am scraping have names alone, names and titles or just titles.

The names can be as varied as John Smith to Vikram Saksena.
I have been poking around for a compiled list of words that can be found in proper names.

Edited I have tried the name set from the Census and it has so much garbage in it that its not worth working with.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [Febrl project source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/febrl/).

It's data folder contains tables for names (given/middle/surnames/etc). You may have to massage the data for your own needs.

For surnames you can check around for U.S. Census data. I don't have the link right now, but know I've used the common U.S. surnames from that source before.